# How to change Vim's unsaved change symbol + to *?

Tags: gvim

By default, the unsaved change symbol is `+` shown ahead of the file name on tab-bar or on title-bar.

Is it possible to change this symbol?

For example, to `*`.

Comment: See `:help setting-tabline` for the TUI and `:help setting-guitablabel` for the GUI.